# Error setting google sheets cell value based on criteria - Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change a range of cells in Column 6 of an excel sheets page based on whether values in a similar range (but in column 3) are larger than its old value. In other words, I am trying to have a column contain all the highs of a constantly changing data set in column 3.

```
function onEdit(evt) {

  var value1 = evt.oldValue;
  var range = evt.range;

  if (range.getRow() >= 2 && range.getRow() <= 7 && range.getColumn() == 3) {

    var value2 = range.getValue();

    if (value2.getValue() > value 1.getValue()) {
      var range2 = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 6);
      range2.setValue(value2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  if (e.range.rowStart>1 && e.range.rowStart<8 && e.range.columnStart==3) {
    if (e.value > e.oldValue) {
      e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(e.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It accurately updated the cells in column 6 with the max values seen in column 3.